# Pystache html characters replaced when using multiple files

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pystache

I am using `pystache` (on Python 3.4) to template HTML files to be sent through email.
I have a `main.mustache` file in which some of the tags are meant to be replaced by content of other `.mustache` files.
So I have something like this (simplified version):

#### main.mustache:

```
<body>
<table>
.......
{{some_params}}
....
</table>

{{special_warning}}
</body>
```

The `{{special_warning}}` tag is only used in some conditions and comes from file `special_warning.mustache`:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h4 style="margin: 0; margin-bottom: 20px;"
        Well, this is odd. please re-do last action.
      </h4>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In my python script I do:

```
special_message = ''
if <some condition>:
    special_message = renderer.render_path('special_warning.mustache', {})

proc_templ = renderer.render_path('main.mustache', {'special_warning': special_message , <the other params>})
```

The result I get is the correct message for the `main.mustache` part but the part coming from `special_warning.mustache` is HTML encoded:

```
<body>
<table>
.......
some_params
....
</table>

&lt;table&gt;
  &lt;tbody&gt;
  ....
  &lt;/tbody&gt;
&lt;/table&gt;

</body>
```

Any ideas how I can prevent this html encoding? Is it python `string` doing it, or the pystache rendering that does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using triple brackets avoids html escaping. so my main.mustache should be:

```
<body>
<table>
.......
{{some_params}}
....
</table>

{{{special_warning}}}
</body>
```